# Using Chart.js on Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to use Chart.js with Angular 4, I saw an example on the chart.js documents but it's using a < script > tag to pull the script so it doesn't work on the component. This is how I tried to fit into Angular:

**TS**

```
export class GraphicsComponent implements OnInit {

  ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["New", "In Progress", "On Hold"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [1,2,3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: false,
      display:true
    }
  });

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="700" height="400"></canvas>
```

Any idea how I would make it work?

**EDIT:** I have updated my code with the import and I'm now receiving an error.

**Import Code:**

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js'
```

**Error on chrome console:**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (platform.dom.js:333)
    at Chart.construct (core.controller.js:74)
    at new Chart (core.js:42)
    at new GraphicsComponent (graphics.component.ts:12)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10922)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10756)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12197)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12092)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13475)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12792)
    at Object.acquireContext (platform.dom.js:333)
    at Chart.construct (core.controller.js:74)
    at new Chart (core.js:42)
    at new GraphicsComponent (graphics.component.ts:12)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10922)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10756)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12197)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12092)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13475)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12792)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:766)
    at zone.js:844
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can install the package, along with the types for full functionality in a typescript environment such as Angular:

`npm install --save chart.js && npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js`

Then in your component you can now `import * as Chart from 'chart.js'` and use it in your typescript environment. Check out [this example](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/chart.js-tests.ts) for implementation methods using typescript.

Because you need to get the canvas from the DOM you need to make sure it's rendered before attempting to access it. This can be accomplished with `AfterViewInit`.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js'

export class MyChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  canvas: any;
  ctx: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
          labels: ["New", "In Progress", "On Hold"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [1,2,3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I did installed and imported but I`m getting an error. See the updated Question.

Comment: @Gustavo There's a couple problems I'm seeing. First one is that you're trying to query the DOM before your components view is even available. Second is you're not getting the 2d context. I'll update my answer shortly to address these

Comment: the types package is now `@types/chart.js`

Comment: I am getting error at display:true. The error is Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'display' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions'.

Comment: @Ahmed *chart.js* has updated their API and no longer supports that option. I have removed it from the answer, which should now work. I suggest using the `[hidden]="isHidden"` to style the HTML DOM directly if you need to hide the item.

Comment: I checked the latest example and it is working now.Thank you so much

Comment: you should also wrap your `<canvas id="myChart" width="700" height="400"></canvas>` inside a div like `<div><canvas id="myChart" width="700" height="400"></canvas></div>` or it has some troubles loading.

Comment: @Z.Bagley What is the significance of this piece of code `npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js`? I mean what does `@types/chart.js` offer other than `chart.js` and why it needs to be added only as a dev dependency?

Comment: @MM It allows typing for your IDE and typescript compiler to make it easier for coding, debugging, and building of your project. It's not a necessity, but it definitely makes the dev processes smoother (TypeScript in general vs plain JavaScript, feel free to do a google to compare the two!).

Answer (score 2):

In my Angular 6.1 site, I am using chart.js by itself in [mgechev/angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed).

As of writing this response, Chart.js developers [have some work to do](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5179) to make exporting its members compliant with newer standards so rollups may be problematic.

To get Chart.js 2.7.x to work after installing package `chart.js` and types `@types/chart.js` in this angular-seed, all I needed to do is:

1. Update `project.config.ts` to include ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS to get rollup to work properly (if you're using a rollup).

   > ```
   > this.ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS = [
   >   ...this.ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS,
   >   { 'node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js': ['Chart'] }
   > ];
   > ```
2. Update `project.config.ts` to include additional packages.  This seed uses SystemJS config.  This might vary if you're using something else.

   > ```
   > // Add packages
   > const additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
   >  { name: 'chart.js', path: 'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js' },
   >
   >   ...
   >
   > ];
   > ```
3. In your component

   > ```
   > import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
   >
   > ...
   >
   > export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   >
   > @ViewChild('myChart') myChartRef: ElementRef;
   > chartObj: Chart;
   >
   > ...
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > Then load chart configuration in ngOnInit() per [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)
4. HTML will look something like this:

   > ```
   > <div class="chart-container">
   >    <canvas #myChart></canvas>
   > </div>
   > ```

Answer (score 2):

So, after a lot of thought, I decided to jump in on this thread, b/c there is an Angular way of doing this that follows best practices and doesn't use any document scope querying... (yuck). For brevity's sake, I've used a `template` in the Component decorator, not a `templateUrl`, but they behave the same as if it were in a template. The DOM still has to e loaded first, and that's the big gotcha with Chart.js. This example is for Angular 8+ and is working with my current version which is 9.1.7

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  template: `<canvas #myChart></canvas>,
})
export class SkillsChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myChart', {
    static: true
  }) myChart: {
    nativeElement: HTMLCanvasElement
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createChart()
  }

  private createChart(): void {
    const elem = this.myChart.nativeElement
    try {
      new Chart(elem, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
          labels: ["New", "In Progress", "On Hold"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [1,2,3],
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
          responsive: false,
          display:true
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err) // You can either throw an error or do whatever here...
    } finally {
      // Any cleanup of logging...
    }
  }

}
```

What's going on here is that you're getting a reference to the Canvas itself, and using Angular's lifecycle hooks to say once the HTML content is initialized, then draw onto the canvas using Chart. The fact that the first argument of Chart is the element itself, this leads to a lot of anti-patterns, but you definitely don't need vanilla JS querying the document scope to get a handle on a specific canvas, and this is the best practice way of doing it according to Angular style guides. If you have concerns, leave them in the comments.

Comment: Great one .. to add we need to `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';`. Referring to docs https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html.