# Error on Chartjs and Angular 5 - "can't acquire context from the given item"

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to display a graph in my Angular project. A simple doughnut chart with 3 datasets. When I try to run the project, the console throws the following error:

**"Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item"**

I've read the documentation, used the templates and even checked on few questions of StackOverflow :

- [chart.js Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280857/chart-js-failed-to-create-chart-cant-acquire-context-from-the-given-item)
- [Using Chart.js on Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328575/using-chart-js-on-angular-4/46328731#46328731)
- [Angular/Chart.js error: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046386/angular-chart-js-error-failed-to-create-chart-cant-acquire-context-from-the-g?rq=1)

None of them worked and I think that it owes to the typescript doesn't "find" the **ID** of the **< canvas >**, but I sincerely don't know what am I doing wrong

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<canvas #grafico id="grafico">{{ grafico }}</canvas>
```

**TypeScript**

```
    import Chart = require('chart.js');

    grafico: any;

    this.grafico = new Chart('grafico',{
    type:"doughnut",
    data:{
      labels: ['Expirados', 'Sem exames', 'Proximo de expirar'],
      datasets:[
        { // Exames expirados
          data:res[0].num_funcion_expir, // Data from API
          backgroundColor:'#EA3100'
        },
        { // Exames expirados
          data:res[0].num_funcion_sem_exam_ini, // Data from API
          backgroundColor:'#ff6384'
        },
        { // Exames expirados
          data:res[0].num_funcion_expir_prox_exam, // Data from API
          backgroundColor:'#EAA900'
        },
      ]
    },
    options:{
      legend:{
        display:true
      }
    }
  });
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You only need to add this to the html template

```
<div [hidden]="!grafico"><canvas id="grafico">{{ grafico }}</canvas></div>
```

[Here is an example of Angular using Chart.JS](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/126/Let's-build-an-Angular-5-Chart.js-App---Tutorial)

Comment: I've actually found a way around it. More difficult, though..
So, many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the canvas with template reference in the component where you are creating the chart.

Component (Use static as true if you are generating the chart in ngOnInit):

```
@ViewChild('grafico',{static:true}) grafico: Chart = [];
```

Template (Because if you are using *ngIf , it removes the element from the dom if the condition evaluates to false) :

```
<div [hidden]="!grafico"><canvas id="grafico">{{ grafico }}</canvas></div>
```

Further more, you can debug the applicatio and verify if the chart is getting created properly or not.

[image]