# Need some Help Regarding Chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have developed a chart application In Angular JS . But I am having a problem with  the data which is showing Y Axis . It should with the increments of 1. But It is getting incremented with 0.2, 0.4 , 0.6 like that . I have attached the screen shot of the same . Can somebody help me regarding this ?

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc4A8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set the stepsize parameter in the [tick configuration object](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html).

Example:

```
let options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                stepSize: 1
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Should yield [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Comment: In JavaScript it is working fine . Can you tell me how can i do it in Angular ?

Comment: You can find an example of how to use chart.js with angular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328731/9281626).