# How to load data in constructor, and render it via Chartjs in ngAfterViewInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-visualization

Here's my problem. A lot of examples of using Chartjs in Angular only assume that [data is already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328575/using-chart-js-on-angular-4), and they render it in `ngAfterViewInit`.

However, I can't figure out how to meet my requirements:

- I need to load data in the constructor
- While loading data, I set a Boolean attribute for showing an indeterminate `mat-spinner`
- Of course, loading data is truly indeterminate, and I can't know when it's loaded (promise land maybe)
- When data is loaded, I need to use Chartjs API to draw data into canvas
- If I do it in the constructor, then I encounter null reference for `document.getElementById('canvasId')`, since it's not rendered yet.
- If I load data in constrcutor and want to render canvas in `ngAfterViewInit`, then I don't know when data is loaded, since it's indeterminate, and I encounter null reference for the properties of my data object.
- If I load data in the `ngAfterViewInit`, then Angular complains that `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'`. This error is related to `mat-spinner *ngIf='progress'`

I'm stuck at this point on how to reconcile these requirements. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

This post uses a service to get data and render the chart after the data is loaded.  Hope it helps!

[Angular Load Data from Service](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/126/Let's-build-an-Angular-5-Chart.js-App---Tutorial)

I was getting the expression changed error but loading and executing in OnInit worked for me.